# Symfony 4 session in service

Tags: php, symfony, session, constructor

I'm trying to use session variables in my custom service.

I already set add the following lines to services.yaml

```
MySession:
    class: App\Services\SessionTest
    arguments: ['@session', '@service_container']
```

And my SessionTest looks like this

```
namespace App\Services;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SessionTest
{
    public $session;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function index()
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($this->session);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

And receive this error:
Too few arguments to function App\Services\SessionTest::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/app.dev/src/Controller/OrdersController.php on line 33 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: From the error message it almost seems like you are trying to new SessionTest(); from the OrdersController?  Furthermore, the __construct you posted does not indicate that the SessionInterface is being injected.

Comment: I already tried it with SessionInterface and receive the same error message

Comment: Very doubtful.  But did you see the first part of my comment?  Are you trying to new SessionTest or are you trying to inject it into the controller?

Comment: yes, I am trying to execute new SessionTest

If I use your edition then receive NULL

Comment: Okay.  The php new operator knows nothing about Symfony's service container.  Check the docs to see how to inject services such as your SessionTest into a controller. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#fetching-and-using-services

Answer (score 0):

You are using constructor injection in your config, but it looks like you're trying to accept property injection in `TestSession`.

The container will be generated with code like approximately this:

`new SessionTest(SessionInterface $session, ContainterInterface $container)`

So you either need to change `TestSession` to accept `'@session'` and `'@service_container'` as constructor arguments:

```
protected $session;
protected $serviceContainer;

public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, ContainterInterface $serviceContainer)
{
    $this->sessions = $session;
    $this->serviceContainer = $container;
}
```

Or you need to change your config to something like this:

```
MySession:
    class: App\Services\SessionTest
    properties:
        session: '@session'
        serviceContainer: '@service_container'
```

You will also need to add

```
   public $serviceContainer;
```

to `TestSession` if you want to inject the service container as a property.